# Intelij Idea - Loading fxml resource from nested directories

Tags: java, fxml, directory-structure

I'm having trouble loading the fxml files from my resource views directory.

I can load it normally without the nested directories but would like to solve it this way for more structural organization.

This is the project structure I modified from Intelij's default.

[image: project_structure]

This is the command I use to load the resource.

```
FXMLLoader homeSceneFXMLLoader = new FXMLLoader(SASAApplication.class.getResource("/views/home-view.fxml"));
```

This command triggers InvocationTargetException and says Location is not set.

I've searched the web for some solutions but my project structure is different so they don't seem to solve my issue.

I want to know how I can correctly access the paths within my project structures so I can have a smooth coding experience.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I started to approach java. I propose this solution (with me it worked) but I am convinced there is a solution that does not increase the complexity of the method. So try this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRzfa.png)

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by excluding the '/' before views/...